# Is (insert into ... select) statement safe about race conditions - SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, race-condition

i have an online hotel booking system which allows multiple users to make bookings almost simultaneously.

When a user requests for free rooms, the system performs a query to get the free rooms and then shows it in a some way ...

Now when user clicks on the "book" button, the free rooms are sent to the server to be booked, i am using a very similar query to this (this is simplified):

```
Insert into Bookings(room_id) select available_room_id from
dbo.GetAvailableRooms(@StartDate,@EndDate) where available_room_id = @ToBeBookedRoomID;
```

where " GetAvailableRooms " is a UDF.

what i am hoping to do by this query is to test for the latest time if room is available or not, but i am worried if this is exposed to race conditions ? i am thinking about the case that some user has booked that room in the time between the insert and select operations ... would "insert into .. select" guarantees no race conditions ?

**Updated:**
 This is the function sql query :

```
select AllDays.day_date,alloted_room_id as available_room_id,pl.room_number from HotelsContractsAllotments hl
inner join PlansRooms pl on pl.room_id = hl.alloted_room_id
inner join HotelsContracts hc on hc.contract_id = hl.allotment_contract_id
inner join Hotels h on h.hotel_id = hc.contract_hotel_id
inner join AllDays on day_date >= hc.contract_starting_date and day_date <= hc.contract_end_date
left join BookingsRooms br on day_date >= br.booking_starting_date and  day_date <= br.booking_end_date and br.booking_room_id = alloted_room_id
where br.booking_room_id is null and day_date >= @StartingDate and day_date <= @EndDate
```

Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing the code from `dbo.GetAvailableRooms`, I would expect this to be exposed to race conditions..

Comment: Sorry, i have just updated it, could you see it please ? @GordonLinoff

Comment: I would suggest using a transaction. Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071286/does-sql-server-wrap-select-insert-queries-into-an-implicit-transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the locking on the table(s), and hints used. Based on the information provided I expect this to be open to race conditions (i.e. a lock is not maintained on the table). You can look at setting-up locks with SQL hits, or transactions. There are a few posts out there that discuss locking. An example of one that looks pertinent to your question is:
[SQL Server Table Lock during bulk insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779312/sql-server-table-lock-during-bulk-insert)

Without a continuous lock on the table(s) affected from the `SELECT` through the `INSERT`, yes you are open to a race condition.

NOTE - locking the table for extended periods will impact performance to varying degrees depending on the volume of traffic, and time locked (if a lot of users are trying to book at the same time, 1sec difference can become significant). Therefore, if you do lock the table, I recommend spending some time tuning your queries for performance. I wont say much on this as I do not have any metrics on your data, or know your indexes. Probably best to start by simply re-structuring your queries to hit the most restrictive table first. I assume this would be the table holding `alloted_room_id` (pass the ID so it can be used in the `WHERE` clause).

Comment: It might be worthwhile to look at the models used for things like online shopping carts and how they handle allocations of 'reserved' resources that expire if the user does nothing.